# How to fix pycharm not recognising templates folder

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates

I have an html template named "homepage.html" and my project is set up like this:

[image]

When running it, however, I get this error:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: D:\lirdi\python\django_blog_project\djangonautic\home\homepage.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\lirdi\python\django_blog_project\interpreter\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\home\homepage.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\lirdi\python\django_blog_project\interpreter\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\home\homepage.html (Source does not exist)
```

Here is my template code:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Homepage</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>This is the homepage</h1>
   <p>Welcome to Djangonautic</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

And for my view:

```
def homepage(reqeust):
    return render(reqeust,'home/homepage.html')
```

And in my settings file:

```
'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template `home/homepage.html` does not exist in the location you specified (there is no folder I can see named '`home`'). Ideally, the templates folder should be in a higher-level directory, directly under the first `djangonautic` folder.

Try instead moving the templates folder to `django_blog_project/djangonautic/templates` and simply using:

```
def homepage(request):
   return render(request,'homepage.html')
```

Make sure the main template directory is specified in your `settings.py` file properly such as:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: but i tried changin templates folder under djangonautic folder and it worked thanks